# Anyone else having trouble with Podio iOS app and Google Street View?

Tags: ios, google-street-view, podio

I have the following code within one of my apps which works perfectly well to show a static "Street View" of a given address:

```
 var prop = @propertyField;
 "![alt-text](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=" + prop + "&fov=70)"
```

The problem is that on the latest Podio app (5.4.0) on iOS (iPhone 6 10.2) , this code is not rendered into an image - the app just displays the list starting "![alt..."

Has anyone got street view working in the Podio iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Podio web app supports [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which provides a mapping from the simple text format of your image link (provided by Google's streetview API) to properly formatted HTML.

Markdown is not currently supported by Podio Mobile, so the iOS App will not automatically render the image located at this URL.

Comment: Hi Kenneth. Thank you so much for getting back to me. I'll keep my fingers crossed for future iOS app updates.